# Need help identifying shower valve brand

Tags: plumbing-fixture

I’d like to replace the shower valve trim in my daughter’s condo.  The existing components aren’t labeled with a brand.  I’m guessing the existing parts are 30 or 40 years old.

Does anybody recognize this based on the photo below?

Many thanks!

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Sencoday Mfg# N1301-9-0 Replacement for Nibco Freedom Shower Handle Clear

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se], thanks for the answer. Please take a look at [how to write a good answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) and consider an [edit] to tell us how you arrived at this information. Considering the number of "identify this plumbing valve" questions we get, knowing _how_ to solve it is almost as important as the solution itself.